# How to compare the data from same table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have table T1 suppose to insert the data into table like

```
w1 A1 
W1 A2
w1 A3
W2 A4 
W2 A5
W2 A6
```

And now I want to insert the data like

```
W3 A1
W3 A2
W3 A4
```

This combination of data should be accept by the table. if I trying to insert same combination like A1 A2 A3 then it should not accept because it's already there for w1.

I am trying to insert the data but I am not getting the way to do

Answer (score 0):

Punctuation exists for reason; without it, it is difficult to guess where one sentence ends and another one begins. You wrote

> This combination of data should be accept by the table if I trying to insert same combination like A1 A2 A3 then it should not accept because it's already there for one W1 columns

What is it, then? Should that combination be accepted, or not? I *translated* it as if it should. I *presume* that there should be a full stop here (after "table"):

> ... by the table. If I try ...

---

Presuming I guessed it right, a simple option is to create unique index on the 2nd column.

```
SQL> create table t1 (col1 varchar2(2), col2 varchar2(2));

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 (col1, col2)
  2    select 'W1', 'A1' from dual union all
  3    select 'W1', 'A2' from dual union all
  4    select 'W1', 'A3' from dual union all
  5    select 'W2', 'A4' from dual union all
  6    select 'W2', 'A5' from dual union all
  7    select 'W2', 'A6' from dual;

6 rows created.
```

Unique index:

```
SQL> create unique index ui1_t1 on t1 (col2);

Index created.
```

Inserting combination (W3, A1) shouldn't be accepted because A1 is already there (for W1):

```
SQL> insert into t1 (col1, col2) values ('W3', 'A1');
insert into t1 (col1, col2) values ('W3', 'A1')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.UI1_T1) violated
```

On the other hand, (W3, A7) should be accepted as A7 wasn't used yet:

```
SQL> insert into t1 (col1, col2) values ('W3', 'A7');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Not like that actually I want to avoid the group entry for w1,w2, is having already then it should not take but in other record or combination from w1,w2 will accept by the table

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Presuming that table contains 6 rows you initially specified, write several pairs of (W, A) values that should be accepted (and why), as well as several (W, A) pairs that should NOT be accepted (and why). Not as a comment - edit the original question.